# Converting from ECEF to geodetic coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, vector, mathematics

I am trying to convert an ECEF coordinate to a geodetic coordinate using [this procedure,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#The_application_of_Ferrari's_solution)  but I don't fully understand the process. It is prefaced by stating the geodetic parameters *{a,b,e,e'}* are assumed to be known, but does not state what they reference to.

I assume that *a* and *b* are the equatorial and polar semi-axes, and that *e* is just Euler's number. Am I correct in this? And what is *e'* supposed to be?

Comment: What software are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MaryBeth I'm writing the conversion as a function in Java. I've researched a few different methods for converting ECEF to Geodetic [(e.g. Zhu referenced by wikipedia)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/303772/), but this one is most easily translatable into Java code. I can't figure out what the known parameters are reference to though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research (from [here](http://sci.fgt.bme.hu/gtoth/ge/geodesy2.pdf) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)#Ellipses)), I believe *e* and *e'* refer to first and second eccentricity, while *a* and *b* do indeed refer to the equatorial and polar semi-axes. Hopefully somebody can confirm this, as I am not 100% certain.

Comment: You're correct. e'^2 is defined in the "The application of Ferrari's solution" and e^2 is defined earlier in the "From geodetic to ECEF coordinates" section.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function to perform the conversion of ECEF coordinates to Geodetic coordinates.

The function is implemented in python but can be easily written in java.

Example:

```
import math

def xyz2llh(x,y,z):
    '''
    Function to convert xyz ECEF to llh
    convert cartesian coordinate into geographic coordinate
    ellipsoid definition: WGS84
      a= 6,378,137m
      f= 1/298.257

    Input
      x: coordinate X meters
      y: coordinate y meters
      z: coordinate z meters
    Output
      lat: latitude rad
      lon: longitude rad
      h: height meters
    '''
    # --- WGS84 constants
    a = 6378137.0
    f = 1.0 / 298.257223563
    # --- derived constants
    b = a - f*a
    e = math.sqrt(math.pow(a,2.0)-math.pow(b,2.0))/a
    clambda = math.atan2(y,x)
    p = math.sqrt(pow(x,2.0)+pow(y,2))
    h_old = 0.0
    # first guess with h=0 meters
    theta = math.atan2(z,p*(1.0-math.pow(e,2.0)))
    cs = math.cos(theta)
    sn = math.sin(theta)
    N = math.pow(a,2.0)/math.sqrt(math.pow(a*cs,2.0)+math.pow(b*sn,2.0))
    h = p/cs - N
    while abs(h-h_old) > 1.0e-6:
        h_old = h
        theta = math.atan2(z,p*(1.0-math.pow(e,2.0)*N/(N+h)))
        cs = math.cos(theta)
        sn = math.sin(theta)
        N = math.pow(a,2.0)/math.sqrt(math.pow(a*cs,2.0)+math.pow(b*sn,2.0))
        h = p/cs - N
    llh = {'lon':clambda, 'lat':theta, 'height': h}
    return llh
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is one of the defining parameters; and `b`, `e`, and `e'` are some of the derived geometric constants of the WGS84 ellipsoid.

`e` is the first eccentricity.  `e'` is the second eccentricity.

See page 3-2 and table 3.5 in [NGA STND 0036_1 0 0_WGS84.pdf](https://nsgreg.nga.mil/doc/view?i=4085)

Answer (score -1):

A better way of doing it can be found at the end of this document:
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01704943v2/document

In this document, it's explained how to do it properly and including a C code so it's easy to copy and paste to see if the solution works.